# L'usage du pronom relatif

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

En étudiant le correct usage des pronoms relatifs simples et composés, j'ai trouvé cette phrase laquelle je ne suis pas sûr je comprends:

> Un fils à l'avenir de qui il songe.

D'abord, j'ai douté pourquoi on utilise *de* dans ce cas alors que le verb **songer** prend la preposition *à*. C'est pour cette raison que j'ai reformulé la phrase comme celle-ci:

> Il songe à un fils à l'avenir.

Et à mon avis, ça devrait tourner en:

> Un fis à l'avenir à qui il songe.

Pourriez-vous me donner une explication quant à le pourquoi la premièr phrase est correcte et ( si c'est le cas de la deuxième aussi ), quelle est la différence entre les deux?

D'autre part, dans cette phrase:

> L'enthousiasme **avec lequel**/**auquel** il a toujours travaillé a été la clé de son succès.

J'avais mis *avec lequel* mais ma professeur m'a corrigé et elle a mit *auquel*. Pourquoi? Je dirais:

> Il a toujours travaillé avec enthousiasme qui a été la clé de son succès.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu as mal compris le sens de

> Un fils à l'avenir de qui il songe.

En fait, une reformulation serait :

> Il songe à l'avenir de son fils.

Ta reformulation veut dire qu'il souhaite avoir un fils, alors que la phrase signifie qu'il souhaite prévoir et préparer l'avenir de son fils.

(He isn't thinking about having a son in future but about his son's future)

La phrase principale est *"il songe"* et "*de qui*" est là pour souligner le fait que *"Un fils"*, même en début de phrase, avant *"à l'avenir"*, est un complément.

`Il songe -> à quoi? -> à l'avenir -> de qui ? -> de son fils`

---

> L'enthousiasme avec lequel/auquel il a toujours travaillé a été la clé de son succès.

Ici le soucis vient principalement du mot *"enthousiasme"*.

Tu peux soit :

- penser qu'il s'agit d'une particularité **passive** de sa personnalité (c'est un bénéfice sans investissement actif)

  > L'enthousiasme avec lequel il a toujours travaillé a été la clé de son succès.

  ->Il travaille avec enthousiasme (que ça soit conscient ou pas) et cela a fait qu'il a eu du succès
- ou alors qu'il a travaillé pour être et paraître *enthousiaste* tous les jours *pour avoir du succès* (il a 'investi' (travailler sur sa personne) pour en récolter le bénéfice).

  > L'enthousiasme auquel il a toujours travaillé a été la clé de son succès.

  Qu'on peut reformuler en

  > Il a travaillé son enthousiasme et cela a été la clé de son succès

Pour ta phrase

> Il a toujours travaillé avec enthousiasme qui a été la clé de son succès.

Il manque un mot pour faire un lien entre la phrase principale et la proposition subordonnée : **ce**.

> Il a toujours travaillé avec enthousiasme **ce** qui a été la clé de son succès.

Comment: Beat me to it. On pourrait ajouter que la première phrase sonne plus naturelle sous la forme *Un fils à l'avenir duquel il songe.*.